# Modify variable inside switch statement for use outside switch

Tags: java, string, android-studio, android-sensors

I am trying to build an Android app that accesses the accelerometer sensor and outputs the accelerometer values, surrounded by <>, to Serial USB when I click a button. I'm having trouble when I update the value and try to call it in the onClick command. How would I do this?

```
switch (sensorType) {
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                float accelX = event.values[0];
                break;

            case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                float magX = event.values[0];
                break;
        }

        final Button buttonAX = findViewById(R.id.Xbutton);
        buttonAX.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String ax = "<"+String.valueOf(accelX)+">";
                serialPort.write(ax.getBytes());
            }
        });
```

Comment: *I'm having trouble* - what trouble?

Answer (score 1):

Try declare variable outside the switch case

```
float accelX=0f, magX=0f;
switch (sensorType) {
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                accelX = event.values[0];
                break;

            case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                magX = event.values[0];
                break;
        }

        final Button buttonAX = findViewById(R.id.Xbutton);
        buttonAX.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String ax = "<"+String.valueOf(accelX)+">";
                serialPort.write(ax.getBytes());
            }
        });
```

Comment: This didn't work. The only value that came out was the initialized value (in this case 0.0) and doesn't send the updated value.

Comment: @JosephSchmidt Check if the switch case block is execute or not (I mean its valid)